# SPFx web part with Graph API not returning Guest user companyName

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, spfx, azure-ad-b2b

Having assigned the User.Read.All permission to a SPFx web part, and Approving it in SPO Admin portal, and also making it a Configured permission (and consenting) it in AD App registration, I'm still not able to query properties such as companyName or postalCode or a **Guest user**, they always come back as null.

I'm using pnp-js to do the query, but same happens if I import the HTTP call to Postman and do the query manually, so there's nothing wrong (apparently) in the call: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/first.last_domain.com%23EXT%23%somecompany.onmicrosoft.com?$select=id,companyName,displayName,givenName,surname,mail,postalCode`

Do I need some additional permission to query non-basic Guest user profile properties?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is related to permission, I think `User.Read.All` permission is enough. I test it in my side, it works fine. So please check if the two fields `companyName` and `postalCode` of the ad guest user is null on your azure portal.
[image]

**Just guess your situation**: Did you add the user from another tenant to current tenant as a guest user ? If so, in current tenant, it will not show the fields such as `companyName` and `postalCode` which shown in original tenant.

Comment: *blush* Looks like I had multiple test Guest accounts and had been updating the properties of a wrong user account.